# Get nul value from one ViewController to one ViewController

Tags: ios

I have 2 ViewControllers namely V1 and V2. I want to pass value from V2 to V1 but I get value 0 for countV1 in V1. I saw more questions in stackoverflow but I can't deal with this small problem. I use ARC.

### In V1

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) int countV1;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize countV1;
```

### In V2

.m file

```
int countV2 = 1;

V1 *v1 = [V1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"V1" bundle:nil];

v1.countV1 = countV2;
```

Comment: do u have one view residing inside another with their separate view controller for each? can u explain your setup here a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I `agree` with `@Alan` for changing "`unsafe_unretained`" to "`readwrite`" for your `countV1` property

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) int countV1;
```

For `id object` for ARC, use :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) id object
```

For `id object` for `non-ARC`, use :

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) id object
```

Now for `backward messaging` of `data` between `controller` its best to use **delegate**

Best `tutorial` for how to use `delegate` [here](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/)

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is that you change "unsafe_unretained" to "readwrite" for your countV1 property, this is a more standard attribute for an int property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) int countV1;
```

This may fix your problem, but if not we really need to see more of your code.  For example, where are you checking the value of countV1?  How are you transferring control to V1?